# Bash script error for syntax operand expected "="

Tags: bash

I get an error in my Bash shell script **script.sh** on this line of code:

`let initialLines=$(grep '' "$1" | wc -l || true)`

error is: `script.sh: line 146: let: initialLines=: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "=")`

What is syntactically incorrect here?

Comment: Not an error, but since every string will match the empty regular expression, your `grep` command is equivalent to `cat "$1"`, in which case you could simply run `wc -l "$1"`.

Comment: @chepner: Good point, but it should be `wc -l < "$1"` (note the `<`), so as to prevent `wc` from outputting the input filename as well.

Comment: @mklement0 Details, details :) I suspect the the regular expression is wrong anyway, which means the pipeline is still relevant. (Although `grep -c` could be used instead as well.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

Double-quote your command substitution:

```
let initialLines="$(grep '' "$1" | wc -l || true)"
```

That said, as explained in [chepner's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41798689/45375), you could just use a simple assignment without needing to double-quote the RHS, although to get the same outcome as with `let` here, be sure to declare the variable with `-i` first; e.g., `declare -i initialLines`

---

It looks like the **RHS of your assignment - the command substitution (`$(...)`) - evaluates either to the *empty* string or a *whitespace-prefixed* string** in the course of the [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) that happen before the command is executed, so that `bash` ends up trying to parse one of the following commands:

```
let initialLines=

let initialLines=   2
```

If you try these in isolation, you'll get the syntax error you've experienced.

---

The most likely explanation is that you're using *BSD* `wc`, such as on macOS, which outputs the line count requested with `-l` with *leading whitespace*.

---

A **simple fix is to *double-quote* the command substitution**:

```
let initialLines="$(grep '' "$1" | wc -l || true)"
```

---

As for the command in your command substitution (it may just be an example, but it's worth commenting on):

- `grep ''` will always return *all* input lines, so it's nothing more than a less efficient `cat`.
- There is no point in using `|| true`:

  - The exit code of the subshell in which the command substitution runs is not relevant, even with `set -e` in effect.
  - Also, by using `true` as the alternative command, you'll break the `let` command as well, because builtin `true` has *no stdout output*.
- In summary, your entire command substitution could be reduced to `wc -l < "$1"`.

Comment: Yes this did get rid of the error and I am using macOS so very knowledgeable answer

Answer (score 2):

There is little or no need to use the `let` command here.

```
initialLines=$(grep '' "$1" | wc -l)
```

This solves the problem (the command substitution producing an empty or white-space prefixed string) pointed out by @mklement0 in a different way; unlike the argument to the `let` command, the value on the right-hand side of an assignment is not subject to word-splitting.

Comment: While good advice in general, there is a subtlety to consider here: to really make the two commands equivalent, you must declare `initialLines` with `-i` first, otherwise just `initialLines=$(grep '' "$1" | wc -l)` will retain leading whitespace, such as the one output by `wc -l` on macOS.